# Split alternating string number appearence

Tags: regex, matlab, string-parsing

Sorry for my question, I am new in regular expressions, I am looking a clever way to split strings of this pattern `A007B001C017D021E041` into `A`, `007`, `B`, `001`, `C`, `017`, `D`, `021`, `E`, `041`. In other words, the input is a `[string][threeDigits]` pattern repeated five times and the output is a separation `[string]`,`[threeDigits]` for every repetition. Could you please give a suggestions using regular expressions of a matlab build-in function?

Thanks.

Comment: The beginning should be `A007B001` right?

Comment: @DVarga yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
tokens = regexp(str, '([a-zA-z])(\d\d\d)', 'tokens');
array = [tokens{:}];
```

Answer (score 1):

A python-based regex solution would look like this - no idea if matlab supports the same regex syntax:

```
$ echo A007B001C017D021E041 | sub '([A-Z])+([0-9]+)' '\1, \2, ' 
A, 007, B, 001, C, 017, D, 021, E, 041,
```

I defined `sub` as an alias like this:

```
alias sub='python -c "import sys, re; regex=re.compile(sys.argv[1]); [ sys.stdout.write(regex.sub(sys.argv[2], line)) for line in sys.stdin ]"'
```

Comment: @yacoob sorry there was a mistake in the given example. I corrected, `A007B001C017D021E041`. There is no `CB` string just `B`.